# Cloudformation: prevent deletion after updates on replacement resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, autoscaling

In AWS Cloudformation there are special resources that can't be updated directly. They are getting replaced with `aws cloudformation update-stack` command instead. This works fine as long as you don't want to keep these resources after an update.

In my example, I want to keep all updated versions of `AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration` resources for manual switching of LaunchConfigurations in the AutoScalingGroup (for testing purposes or emergency rollback). I need to do that, because web interface users are not able to use Cloudformation, nor are they authorized to do so.

So i created a template which creates/updates a LaunchConfiguration resource by setting a custom `LaunchConfigurationName` with including current date/time.
This works for fine, but:
after `UPDATE_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS` state the old version of `AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration` resource always gets deleted. To avoid that i tried to setup a set-stack-policy:

```
{
  "Statement" : [
    {
      "Effect" : "Allow",
      "Action" : "Update:*",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Resource" : "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect" : "Deny",
      "Action" : "Update:Delete",
      "Principal" : "*",
      "Resource" : "*",
      "Condition" : {
        "StringEquals" : {
          "ResourceType" : ["AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration"]
        }
      }
    }  
  ]
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/protect-stack-resources.html

```
Update:Delete

    Specifies update actions during which resources are removed. 
    Updates that completely remove resources from a stack template require this action.
```

result: The resource still gets deleted after updating the AutoScalingGroup (`UPDATE_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS` state). 
Do you have an idea how to keep old versions?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the deletion policy to `RETAIN` and also change the logical id of the resource. Changing the logical id of the resource causes Cloudformation to delete the old resource (or retain it based on the deletion policy) and create a new one. It works like this because cloudformation does know that you've changed the logical id. It sees it as one resource being removed and one being added.

Comment: I know this. But that's not my usecase. I don't want to delete the entire stack.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html

And no, this doesn't work here.

Comment: From that link: Note that this capability also applies to stack update operations that lead to resources being deleted from stacks.